# collapsing graphs according to a common parameter in iGraph [Python]

Tags: python, igraph

I have an igraph network g where all edges' weights are 1 and where all vertices belong to on of 5 groups (noted with a vertex parameter called "group").

Now I want to make a new graph G where the vertices of g are collapsed, ore contracted, according to the group they belong to. So that the number of vertices of G is reduced to the number of different groups in g, and the edges between these new collapsed vertices have a weight equal to the summed up number of edges between the same groups in g.

I believe I could use contract_vertices(). But the edges' weights wouldn't be added, I'm guessing... Anyway, is there a way to accomplish this in igraph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contract_vertices()` followed with `simplify()`, which can collapse the edges and sum the weights:

```
g2 = g.copy()
g2.contract_vertices(membership)
g2.simplify(combine_edges={"weight": sum})
```

Comment: Great, thanks (iGraph is so impressive)! As far as the membership goes, is there a way to build an array out of the parameter "group"?

Comment: ("group" being a string)